# Контрол на основе старого

Tags: c#, winforms

Создаю контрол TabPage на основе старого:

```
public partial class TabControl2 : TabControl
{
  [Browsable(false)]
  [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
  public new TabPageCollection TabPages { get; } // скрыли родную коллекцию страниц

  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
  public List<TabPage> UserPages { get; set; } = new List<TabPage>(); // новая коллекция страниц
}
```

Мне требуется внедрить новую коллекцию страниц, чтобы в дизайнере можно было добавлять/удалять страницы и устанавливать у них нужные свойства(*public List* - класс *TabPage* будет расширен, в него будут добавлены новые свойства). При текущем объявлении свойство видимо в дизайнере, функционирует - но не полностью(код из файла форма.Designer.cs):

```
   this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();

   // 
   // tabPage1
   // 
   this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
   this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
   this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
   this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
   this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";

   private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
```

Как видно - страница создалась, но не вызвался метод Add свойства Control родительского объекта. Как правильно объявить новое свойство UserPages, чтобы в 
файле форма.Designer.cs код генерировался полностью?

Comment: если вы посмотрите в [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/TabControl.cs,2351), то увидите, что `TabPageCollection` это специализированная обертка над коллекцией `Controls` родительского `TabControl`, а не обычный лист, и добавление на самом деле происходит не в оторванный от контекста список, как у вас. Так что поведение в вашей реализации, ровно такое, какое вы и описали, ну да, это не совпадает с вашими желаниями, но тут уж как сформулировали желание, так и работает.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще решили заменить специализированную коллекцию? Чем она вас не устроила?

Comment: Наследники `TabPage` будут нормально добавляться и редактироваться, пропишете видимость свойств в дизайнере и не будут отличаться от оригинальных в плане визуального редактирования.

Comment: @rdorn наверное, в этом главный вопрос и состоит: сделав наследника TabPage, как обеспечить нужную видимость новых свойств, для отображения их в дизайнере? И, свойство TabPages увидит наследников сразу, без доп. Настроек?

Comment: Вот этот вопрос и надо было задать. Я посмотрел как работает дизайнер студии... да, сам по себе он умет добавлять только стандартные табы. Кастомные можно добавлять без проблем в коде. Если принципиально научить дизайнер добавлять кастомные табы, то надо взять исходники коллекции по ссылке и модифицировать для работы с нужным типом табов. Беда в том, что вы не сможете научить дизайнер работать с разными типами табов, поэтому если предполагается более одного наследника, то придется все делать в коде.

Comment: В теории это наверное можно сделать, но судя по тому, что сторонние UI фреймворки (тот же DevExpress например) используют собственные дизайнеры для своих составных контролов, предполагаю что это далеко не тривиальная задача.

Comment: @rdorn подозревал, что не очень простое задание. Изначально кодом и сделал, просто решил уточнить. Напоследок, вдруг Вы знаете ответ: при размещении на форме TabControl автоматически создаются две TabPages. Исходники читал, место, где генерируются страницы - не нашёл. А вот от этого хотелось бы избавиться. Премного.

Comment: Могу посоветовать [PropertyGrid FAQ](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml).

Comment: По поводу генерации страниц не знаю. Многие контролы генерируют демо-данные. В исходниках этого нет, наиболее вероятно, что это прописано где-то в скриптах интеграции со студией, но эти исходники я не знаю где смотреть. Да и для кастомного контрола должно само отсохнуть

Comment: Нашел [виновного](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Design/System/Windows/Forms/Design/TabControlDesigner.cs,f09e0bcefe08ba1b) в заполнении. Решаемо. Нужно прописать в атрибутах кастомного контрола кастомный дизайнер, но исходники ILSpy не видит, из-за internal. DotPeek видит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подведу краткий итог исследования вопроса и обсуждения в комментариях:

То что вы хотите реализовать можно, но придется руками писать дизайнер, который сможет подхватить студия.

Для этого понадобится создать наследника [ParentControlDesigner](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.parentcontroldesigner?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), оригинал можно подсмотреть с помощью DotPeek (другими до internal классов добраться не удалось) в [System.Windows.Forms.Design.TabControlDesigner (System.Design.dll)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Design/System/Windows/Forms/Design/TabControlDesigner.cs,f09e0bcefe08ba1b)

Когда все будет готово, повесить на кастомный контрол [DesignerAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
[Designer("<namespace>.CustomTabControlDesigner")]
class CustomTabControl : TabConrol { ... }
```

Непосредственно реализация дизайнера и контрола останется за рамками данного вопроса, я не слишком силен в данной магии, чтобы понятно и кратко изложить только необходимое, но если кто-то наберется энтузиазма и осилит, я с удовольствием почитаю. (может когда-нибудь и сам соберусь, но это не точно)

---

Замечания по поводу специализированной коллекции для вложенных табов, остаются в силе, однако с учетом изучения кода штатного дизайнера, это не позволит получить сколь-нибудь существенное облегчение работы, так как создание стандартных `TabPage` "прибито гвоздями", и для изменения данного поведения дизайнера придется его переписывать.

Comment: Гигантское! Буду разбираться.

Comment: @Range взаимно, вопрос оказался гораздо интереснее чем показалось сначала =)

Comment: Обычно так и бывает:) Я планировал разобраться с этим за день, а вышло...каплю больше :)